# How can I tell if a horse likes me?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

In RDR, how can I tell which horse I have? There doesn't seem to be any menu for it. Do I have to go entirely by the pictures on the wiki site? That doesn't seem like very good game design to rely on a strategy guide or 3rd party website.

Also, they said the horse would get more attached to me over time, and way back at McFarland ranch i remember getting status messages that this was happening, but now it doesn't happen anymore? Is there a screen that would show me how the horse is feeling?

Comment: 5-legged horses probably like you.

Comment: I thought about tagging this as xbox-360 and realized it's unnecessary, because there is no PC version, then I became sad :_(

Comment: @Nick T - I nominate that for comment of the year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Identifying the breed of the horse is done by sight alone.** If you review the deeds in the general store, they'll give you a description of how the breed looks. Beyond that, [pictures on game guides](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Horse_Breeds) are your best bet.

If you're not purchasing the deed from a general store, you will have to determine the quality by the appearance of the horse. Skinny mounts are 1-star mounts, large mounts with tons of muscles are 3-star mounts, and anything in the middle is a 2-star mount.

**The only indication I know of in terms of loyalty is an increase in your horses overall stamina as it becomes more loyal.** There is no in-game menu that shows this information, much to the chagrin of the community:

- [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/957922-red-dead-redemption/54869880)
- [GameFAQs 2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/957923-/54855033)
- [GameFAQs 3](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/957922-red-dead-redemption/54874205)
- [IGN](http://boards.ign.com/red_dead_redemption/b6186/192309570/r192334042/)

Comment: That's what I thought. Bit of an oversight if you ask me, but at least now I can stop looking for it. thanks!